# Rain Water enters through tracks of sliding glass windows

Tags: windows

I have sliding glass windows on Aluminium tracks and when it rains heavily (especially when it is windy) the rain water comes in on the window sill & wets the wall underneath.

The water seems to be filling the window tracks & then entering. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Edit:

I am adding a photo of the window tracks. The weep holes seem present and unblocked? There's a trio of aligned holes on the track rails. This is a three panel horizontal sliding window.

For approx. a 6 ft horizontal span of window there seem to be three sets of holes laterally. Do I need more holes? Larger holes?

What else could be the problem? The water influx seems to only happen when it rains heavily and on windy days. Being in a subtropical climate the thunderstorms can be quite severe.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The lower track of a window frame normally is supposed to have small holes at its lower edge toward the outside that allows water in the track to drain out. These are commonly called weep holes.

It is a common problem that over years dirt can collect on the bottom of the track and clog up these holes so the track will no longer drain. Look to see if yours are clogged and clean if necessary.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I added a photo of my setup. The weepholes seem there and not blocked. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @curious_cat - I do not have any other ideas. It is known that some windows will leak when blasted from the outside with a garden hose or power washer. An intense storm would be similar. It could be that your window design is just not up to the conditions to which it is exposed. You may be faced with having to do research to find a suitable replacement window or a possible storm window add-on that you install in the rainy season.

Answer (score 1):

The tracks and their weep-holes in the picture look perfect. So, I'd suspect that there's a crack in the tracks or that you need to re-caulk the bottom of the window unit on the outside or that the sashes need new seals.

If a metal unit, you can cheat the sash seals by pinching the tracks slightly closed with pliers to re-tighten the tracks to the sash seals. If that works, then you'd want to repeat it on the entire window to restore heating or cooling efficiency to the place.

The tracks are usually, and seem to be here as well, a single piece. But, they're commonly poorly joined miters at the corners. You'll need to caulk the corners, if the water's coming in at the window ends.